# Delete Key Value of localstorage in javascript (json object)

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, local-storage

Hello I know there are many questions similar to this but nothing fits my problem.

I have a key value in my localstorage called 'productsInCart'. This key value contains a JSON object which looks like this:

```
{"11011001":{"id":11011001,"name":"42 Cable","price":4,"inCart":1},"11011002":{"id":11011002,"name":"22 Cable","price":4,"inCart":1}}
```

Now i want to delete/remove one value for example the value with the id '11011002'. How can I do that?

What I tried so far:

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productsInCart"));
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                               var items = JSON.parse(items[i]);
                               if (items.item_id == item_id) {
                                   items.splice(i, 1);
                               }
                           }
                           items = JSON.stringify(items);
                           localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", items);
```

I know this wont work because its not an array, but maybe someone has an idea on how to change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: `delete items['11011002']`

Comment: @pilchard yes it works but it deletes the json object only temporarly when i try to put the object back in the localstorage with 'localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", items);' i get an error

Comment: You need to stringily it first: `localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(items));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you pull it out from localStorage you need to transform it to an array and then filter it by your criteria:

Example:

```js
const storage = {
  "11011001": {
    "id": 11011001,
    "name": "42 Cable",
    "price": 4,
    "inCart": 1
  },
  "11011002": {
    "id": 11011002,
    "name": "22 Cable",
    "price": 4,
    "inCart": 1
  }
};


const list = Object.keys(storage).map(key => ({
  [key]: storage[key]
}));
const filteredList = list.filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0] !== '11011002');
console.log(filteredList)
```

Setting the new structure into the localStorage use this:
`localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(filteredList))`

Comment: ok, but how do i remove it now from the localstorage?

Answer (score 1):

So the suggestion by pilchard was right i just needed to delete the Object with

```
delete items[item_id];
```

and after that put it back in the localstorage with

```
items = JSON.stringify(items);
localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", items);
```

This worked fine for me, thanks

Comment: you should consider using functional approach whenever possible and make use of the available methods like filter in this case, anyhow +1